# How to find Number with most divisor from array

Tags: java, arrays, integer-division

I have an array and i want to find number with most divisor. The problem is that i can find the number but i cant print how many divisor it is.

```
static void printDivisors(int n)
{
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if (n%i==0)
            System.out.print(i+" ");
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("The divisors of 100 are: ");
    printDivisors(100);;
}
```

}

Comment: You should include your attempt and describe the problem you are having.  See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you only need to check values between `1` and `n/2` to find the divisors of `n`. You won't find a divisor between `n/2` and `n` (except for `n` itself). This will effectively reduce your execution time by half.

So your divisor finding method can be improved like below to count the number of divisors of a given number.

```
static int getNumDivisors(int n) {
    int noOfDivisors = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            noOfDivisors++;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        noOfDivisors++; // n itself is a divisor of n
    }
    return noOfDivisors;
}
```

Then you need to iterate through the `numbers` array given by user and find the number of divisors for each number.

While iterating you need 2 variables

- `currentMaxDivisors` - to store the max no of divisors you have found so far
- `numWithMaxDivisors` - which number had the above number of divisors

If you happen to find a new number with more divisors, you update these variables with the new values. At the end, `numWithMaxDivisors` variable will contain the number with maximum divisors.

```
static int getNumDivisors(int n) {
    int noOfDivisors = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            noOfDivisors++;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        noOfDivisors++; // n itself is a divisor of n
    }
    return noOfDivisors;
}

static int getNumWithMaxDivisors(int[] numbers) {
    // Assuming numbers array has at least one element
    int currentMaxDivisors = 0;
    int numWithMaxDivisors = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int numDivisors = getNumDivisors(numbers[i]);
        if (numDivisors > currentMaxDivisors) {
            numWithMaxDivisors = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return numWithMaxDivisors;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[]{100, 55, 67, 2003, 12};
    int numWithMaxDivisors = getNumWithMaxDivisors(numbers);
    System.out.println(numWithMaxDivisors);
}
```

Comment: thank u, but for ex. i have array [ 5, 22, 21,8,10] and it prints me the same numbers like before, i think its really great method ( if i good understand) it takes array[0] and checks how many divisors it have, than second loop takes array[1] and if array [1] has more divisors than goes to int currentMaxDivisor right ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: okay, so for ex.
i have array [ 1, 2 , 3, 7, 20] (number with most divisor will be 20-1,2,4,5 etc.)
and i want to get 20 because it's the number with most divisor.

Comment: The above `getNumWithMaxDivisors` method will get you `20` for that array. Anyway I have removed the unnecessary print statements as you may have got confused by them. Please check now.